# How to convert a Array of Map object with values to a single Map

Tags: scala

How to convert,   Array of Map to a single Map

```
Array(Map(k1 -> v1), Map(k2 -> v2),  Map(k3 -> v3), Map(k4 -> v4))
```

to a single Map object

```
Map(k1 -> v1, k2 -> v2, k3 -> v3, k4 -> v4)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
val arr = Array(Map("k1" -> "v1"), Map("k2" -> "v2"), Map("k3" -> "v3"), Map("k4" -> "v4"))
arr.flatten.toMap
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val m = arr.flatMap(identity).toMap
```